# Revoke consent using Azure v2.0

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Azure v2.0 for user authentication. The access token that I receive is used to fetch onenote content using microsoft graph api. And I do store refresh token at my end to access content on behalf of user at any time. Now user opt's out of my system I want to revoke the permissions given by user to my app.

How I can revoke the access without depending on user for that. User may not manually go and revoke the permissions. Is there any api provided for same purpose.

Is there any api provided by Azurev2.0 for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delayed response here.  Unfortunately we don't have a specific revocation API.  And while this is theoretically possible through existing APIs, where the `oauth2Permission` resource type holds the consent grant (see https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/oauth2permissiongrant_delete), your app will need to be granted a privileged permission to perform this action.  Contrary to the linked topic, I don't believe that the `Directory.ReadWrite.All` application permissions actually allows this operation.

Please create a [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis) request to ask for this API.

Hope this helps,