# Is there any way to revoke Azure Active Directory application consent with Microsoft Graph-Api

Tags: azure, sharepoint, office365, microsoft-graph-api

Is there actually any way to revoke Azure Active Directory application consent with Microsoft Graph-Api? I know that i can be done at:
https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/r#/applications
But is there any way to do it without user having to leave my page?

Any other ideas how do do it without leaving the page is also welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Revoke consent using Azure v2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45056429/revoke-consent-using-azure-v2-0)

Comment: Even if the API is not supporting it, i'm wondering if there's any way to do it without user leaving the page. Lets say using something similar to IFrame(not working in this case).